# Efficient way to get json nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting data from an api and am trying to figure out the most efficient way to test if there is more than one child of a given node. For example I might have two different items and is how they are received after a query:

1st Item:

```
content:
    EMPLOYEE:
      ADDITIONALLANGUAGES:
         ADDITIONALLANGUAGE:
           LANGUAGE: "Spanish"
```

2nd Item:

```
content:
    EMPLOYEE:
      ADDITIONALLANGUAGES:
         ADDITIONALLANGUAGE:
           [0]{LANGUAGE: "Punjabi"}
           [1]{LANGUAGE: "Hindi"}
```

For the first item I can reference by:
content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE

but this doesn't work for the second item.

If I reference like so:
content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE[0]
I get undefined on the first item.

I'm looking for a more elegant way to check if more than one additional language shows rather than writing:

```
if (content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE[0]){
  //do stuff
} else {
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/

Comment: How about using `length` , ```content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE.length```

Comment: Can you provide the real JSON? It's difficult to tell whether something is an array or object with the pseudo-code provided.

Comment: the approach you write in your question is the fastest and most convenient solution, or using `isArray` is acceptable: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp

Comment: @VietPhan _"the approach you write in your question is the fastest and most convenient solution"_ What approach are you referencing? "fastest" compared to? How do you evaluate "most convenient"? For whom?

Comment: @guest271314 OP just look for the way to check if more than one additional language, don't exaggerate this little thing too much. if you want the code more readable, so using `isArray`

Comment: @VietPhan The approach using `if` will throw an error if the property is an object. Instead of checking for the type of object, you can convert the property to a single type to avoid having to use `if` statement and `.isArray()`

Comment: I'll try isArray. Thanks. length wasn't working as expected but could've perhaps been worked in a different way. Thanks!

Comment: @BryanDellinger that worked best for my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatentate and assign the single object to an array of objects, which will convert the first pattern to the second pattern, and will not affect the second pattern when the array is spread to a new array

```
content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE = [].concat(...[content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE]);
```

You will then be able to consistently use

```
content.EMPLOYEE.ADDITIONALLANGUAGES.ADDITIONALLANGUAGE[0 /* N */];
```